# Pulling FIle in from Google Drive - urllib

Tags: python, function, urllib

I'm trying to get this code to work and I'm not sure what's going on. My advisor wrote part of it and I'm tasked with adding a few other if statements to pull in data from different folders. Here's the code with URL's changed:

```
import os
import urllib.request
import fabio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def get_test_pattern(sample=None):

    if sample is None:
        data_url = 'https://drive.google.com/a/....'
        file_name = 'file_name1'
        data_dir = os.path.join('tempdata', 'drive')

    elif sample is 'water':
        data_url = 'https://drive.google.com/a/....'
        file_name = 'file_name_2'
        data_dir = os.path.join('tempdata', 'drive')

    else:
        raise ValueError('Name is invalid')

    file_path = os.path.join(data_dir, file_name)

    if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
        print('Fetching example data file')
        os.makedirs(data_dir, exist_ok=True)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(data_url, file_path)

    image = fabio.open(file_path)
    data = image.data

    plt.imshow(data)
    plt.show()
    return data
```

The image plotting is just to see if I can get the file, I'll be removing it eventually. The Fabio package just opens a specific file type we're working with. I left it in for completion.

When I run it with the argument `sample=none`, it works fine, but when I switch to `sample='water'`, it throws an "invalid data stream" error. I'm still pretty new with Python, so my issue may very well be very basic.